# React Native Facebook Login using official fbsdk

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I tried following the starter [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login) by setting up a new React Native Project for iOS. But the loginbutton doesn't seem to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the index.ios.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton
} = FBSDK;

var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                alert("login has finished with permissions: " + result.grantedPermissions)
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Login to Facebook
        </Text>
        <Login />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  shareText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 10,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

And the screenshot of the emulator:
[image: enter code here]

Comment: Is the problem with the functionality or the styling?

Comment: Functionality: clicking on the button doesn't do anything. Could the deprecation warning have something to do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to link the sdk's iOS project in your app's project.

If you're using react-native-sdk v0.2.0+, rnpm will take care of this step and you can follow the tips [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/releases) to complete set up.

If you're using the older version, you need to link react-native-fbsdkxxx.xcodeproj in YourApp.xcodeproj. Follow the manual linking steps in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll try it out later. Just curious, how come Android works fine without loading a library manually like iOS?

Comment: Because the Android project uses gradle. It pulls the library from server and setup things for you automatically.

Comment: I have recived confirmation: ```rnpm-install info Android module react-native-fbsdk is already linked
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-fbsdk is already linked```   yet Still a red box ??