# Facebook React Native SDK LoginButton renders UnimplementedView with red border in Android

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

This question pertains to Facebook's React Native SDK *and* only in Android, as iOS renders `LoginButton` fine:

[image: iOS renders LoginButton fine]

#### In Android, I see this instead:

[image]

I'm on `react-native 0.41.2`.  I've followed [the configurations for React-Native v0.30+](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current). I've also done all [the configurations in Android for Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/808734535832729/?platform=android).

I found a [similar thread for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230420/react-native-facebook-login-using-official-fbsdk) with the same problem. The solution there was to make sure that the SDK is linked in the iOS project. I've gone over several times to make sure the SDK is linked in the Android project. I feel like I'm taking crazy pills; it's probably something really minor, but I can't seem to see it.

My `MainActivity.java` is:

```
package com.myapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    CallbackManager mCallbackManager = MainApplication.getCallbackManager();
    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MyApp";
    }

//    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        mCallbackManager = new CallbackManager.Factory().create();
        ReactPackage packages[] = new ReactPackage[]{
                new MainReactPackage(),
                new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
        };
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(packages);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

My `MainApplication.java` is:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import io.realm.react.RealmReactPackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new RealmReactPackage(),
          new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

I've added `facebook_app_id` to `strings.xml`. I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I have `compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')` in the `dependencies` block for my app's `build.gradle`. My `settings.gradle` has:

```
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
```

Package name matches the one I saved in FB's developer console. I've generated and uploaded development key hash. I feel like I've exhausted everything -- it's probably exhausting you read this far and I really thank you for that!!

One clue I found was using the inspector, which shows me `UnimplementedView` nested inside `LoginButton`:

[image]

I've searched for `UnimplementedView` but nothing turns up. In `react-native log-android`, I get these errors:

02-17 09:37:10.877  2977  3007 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLikeView" does not exist
  02-17 09:37:10.878  2977  3007 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: Native component for "RCTFBLoginButton" does not exist
  02-17 09:37:10.878  2977  3007 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: Native component for "RCTFBSendButton" does not exist
  02-17 09:37:10.878  2977  3007 W ReactNativeJS: Warning: Native component for "RCTFBShareButton" does not exist

I haven't found any Android related solutions on StackOverflow, though. I've only found [an iOS thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960415/react-native-fbsdk-in-ios), which again sounds like a link problem.

I'm guessing I've linked the SDK incorrectly somehow, but I don't know where I screwed up.

Any help will be super appreciated!! Thank you!

-Connie

Answer (score 2):

72 hours later. Killed and restarted the app in Android simulator. Login button magically reappears! Not sure how or why. Hope only my time was wasted on this.

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you!